# Environment Variables with Firebase Config and Next.js

Tags: firebase, next.js, environment-variables

I'm trying to use a .env with Next.js and Firebase config.

When I use the variable itself it works normally but when I add it on the .env and use it on the config it doesn't work anymore.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FBASE_APP_ID
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebaseApp
```

My next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      { protocol: "https", hostname: "m.media-amazon.com", port: "" },
      { protocol: "https", hostname: "lh3.googleusercontent.com", port: "" },
      { protocol: "https", hostname: "t4.ftcdn.net", port: "" },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I'm using Next and firebase on the latest version of both, already tried adding quotes, setting 'as string' an everything on the process.env

I don't know if it's normal but the returning of it is undefined when used on `console.log`, the .env is on the root of the app and I changed to `FBASE` because I was afraid of using variables that are already used by the program

Comment: could you please share your `next.config.js` file?

Comment: @AsMdHabibullah Added just now friend!

Comment: That I thought, you made a mistake in your setup`next.config.js` file. I'm answering your question. just a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firebase app** setup is correct but you made a mistake in your `next.config.js` file. `NextJs` can read but can't supply the `.env` variable directly to the client app.

Install `dotenv` package: `npm install dotenv`

The update of your `next.config.js` file for the `.env` setup will be

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

require("dotenv").config()

const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    FIREBASE_APIKEY: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    FBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: process.env.FBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    FBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: process.env.FBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    FBASE_APP_ID: process.env.FBASE_APP_ID
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      { protocol: "https", hostname: "m.media-amazon.com", port: "" },
      { protocol: "https", hostname: "lh3.googleusercontent.com", port: ""},
      { protocol: "https", hostname: "t4.ftcdn.net", port: "" },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**Note:** The `.env` files variable name must be the same as the nextConfigs `env` object.

Your .env file must contain `variable name= value`

```
FIREBASE_APIKEY=
authDomain=
FBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=
FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=
FBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=
FBASE_APP_ID=
```

After you update your `next.config.js` file, your `firebase` app setup file can access the `.env` variable through `process.env.*`.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FBASE_APP_ID
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebaseApp
```

Comment: That is exacly the problem, much thanks friend. Happy to see people so smart here!

Comment: Hope you will enjoy your dev journey, and stay with `overflow` :)